# How do I get the console to println for core data in a separate view for Swift?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I have put together some picker views with the choices going to Core Data.  I'd like to confirm that I actually set it up correctly by printing to the console.  However, when I run the app, the console remains blank.  Am I missing a step?

My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func saveTapped(Sender : AnyObject) {

let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    let contxt: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    let en = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Outgoing", inManagedObjectContext: contxt)

    var newItem = Outgoing(entity: en!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contxt)
    newItem.item1 = pickerView1.textInputContextIdentifier!
    newItem.item2 = pickerView2.textInputContextIdentifier!
    newItem.item3 = pickerView3.textInputContextIdentifier!



    contxt.save(nil)

    println(newItem)

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)


}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is that method being called ? Put some text also in that println and check whether that is printing or not

Comment: The method wasn't being called, and it wasn't printing anything else in the console.  I updated it and it is now functioning correctly.